# Pass Array & Multidimensional Array from Android to PHP

Tags: php, android, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have my Android Java code that have to pass some array and some multidimensional array to the PHP Server. Unfortunately, I don't have the access to the PHP Server.

Here's the PHP Server API :

```
$result= array(
    "username" => "admin",
    "password" => "admin",
    "hobbies" => array(
                "1" => "science"
     ),
    "skills" => array(
                "1" => array(
                        "Boxing" => "Yes"
                    )
     )
);
```

Here's my Android Java Code :

```
final String hobbies[] = {"science"};
final String skills[][] = {{"Boxing"},{"Yes"}};

@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> jParams= new HashMap<String, String>();

JSONArray arrHobbies = new JSONArray();
JSONArray arrSkills = new JSONArray();
arrHobbies.put(hobbies[0]);
arrSkills.put(skills[0][0]);

jParams.put("username", "admin");
jParams.put("password", "admin");
jParams.put("hobbies",arrHobbies.toString();
jParams.put("skills",arrSkills.toString();

return jParams;
}};
```

Then, I use this code to see how the data've been sent.

```
Log.d("Response : ", jParams.toString());
```

It shows this on the Android Log :

```
{password=admin, username=admin, hobbies=["science"], skills=[["275]]}
```

**UPDATE**
Here's the hash values when I debug the code:

```
 0 = {java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry@4884} "hobbies" -> "{"1":"1"}"
 1 = {java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry@4885} "password" -> "admin"
 2 = {java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry@4886} "username" -> "admin"
 3 = {java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry@4887} "skills" -> "{"1":{"Boxing":"Yes"}}"
```

I never succeed to communicate with the PHP Server API.
Please help me where am I missing or wrong.

Comment: What is it supposed to log? because thats logging exactly what you are creating? I suspect you are not understanding what `skills[][]` is actually creating

Answer (score 1):

there is a library how call GSON, search it on internet
it's the fastest and simplest way to resolve String to Json and Json to String.

Comment: Hi Sir, thanks for your answer, I will keep this answer for the backup plan, Cause I have more than 5 Activities, and i will prefer if i get the solution from using JSON

Comment: it's the simplest way, trust me. GSON is the most powerful solution

Comment: I'll give it a try then :)

Comment: you can use Volley or Spring to get data, and work with Gson for calculate and scrolling data

Comment: yup, i already used Volley, i think it's all about format of the data sent to the server

Comment: unfortunately I'm not expert in PHP, but as I know JSON Object is the best way

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that **associative array** in php represents **JSON object** in your json string so you probably should send something like this to your PHP Server API:

```
{
    "password": "admin",
    "username": "admin",
    "hobbies":{
        "1": "science"
    },
    "skills": {
        "1": {
            "Boxing": "Yes"
        }
    }
}
```

Here i can't be 100% sure and it depends on your server implementation, but to achieve the json output from above, your getParam() should look like this:

```
protected String getParams() {
    JSONObject jParams = new JSONObject();

    try {
        JSONObject arrHobbies = new JSONObject();
        arrHobbies.put("1", "science");


        JSONObject boxing = new JSONObject();
        boxing.put("Boxing", "Yes");

        JSONObject arrSkills = new JSONObject();
        arrSkills.put("1", boxing);


        jParams.put("username", "admin");
        jParams.put("password", "admin");

        jParams.put("hobbies", arrHobbies);
        jParams.put("skills", arrSkills);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jParams.toString();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, May I ask you something? Is it the same with password=admin (Android) and "password" : "admin" (PHP Server)

Comment: no it is different. `"password" : "admin"`  is json representation of key => value and if you put  password=admin in json it will be invalid. http://pro.jsonlint.com/ here is nice tool to check json validity. You PHP server will probably try to just use [this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode your json. And here is also how i got the json you server probably asks: [LINK](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/77e2adbd1580fe43e13dcaa77eb90926fb904fcd)

Comment: Hi, do you mind to look my edited post above, I posted the hash values when I debug the code. Does the format correct? Cause I still got the error

Comment: If you use volley, you can  try to send `JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,URL, new JsonObject(hashMap),` instead of HashMap. I usualy do similar tasks this way. 1) install [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) 2) make sure it works in postman so you 100% sure what server expects from you. 3) create JSONObject that will produce the same json string as your postman 4) play with Volley or Retrofit to send your json.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help you :

@Override
 protected Map getParams() {

```
    Map<String, String> jParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

    JSONArray arrHobbies = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray arrSkills1 = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray arrSkills2 = new JSONArray();

    arrHobbies.put("science");
    arrSkills1.put("Boxing");
    arrSkills1.put("Yes");

    arrSkills2.put(arrSkills1);


    jParams.put("username", "admin");
    jParams.put("password", "admin");
    jParams.put("hobbies", arrHobbies.toString());
    jParams.put("skills", arrSkills2.toString());

    return jParams;
}
```